# The server was unable to save the form at this time. please try again

Tags: list, permissions, error

I'm receiving the following error message when trying to add or update a list item.

> "the server was unable to save the form at this time. please try
>   again"

The list has some folders and I assigned special permissions on each folder.

When I'm logged in as *Folder X User* I can't edit list items inside this folder, even though my group has full control on this folder.

I can edit normally when I log in as *administrator*.

Answer (score 2):

**In case you got this error for all users.**

- SharePoint Search Host Controller service may need to restart to free up some memory space.
- Anonymous Authentication was disabled in IIS.
- “minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService” attribute is not set to serviceHostingEnvironment Tag in Web.Config.
- The farm wasn’t updated with at least March 2013 PU / Service Pack 1.

**In case you got this error for a specific user.**

- If your list has unique permissions and a user/group has permissions only on that list and has limited or no access at the site level, then you run into this error.

> For more details check [**The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again in SharePoint 2013**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

OK the fix is that *Folder X User* need at least read permission on the site besides the fact you assign full control on the list folder